# segment fault when I use shmat

Tags: c, memory, posix, sharing

When I reach the line `routerInfo->areaID`, I got segment fault: 11 on that part.
It seem that I do not allocate the memory successfully. 
I just do not know why.
Can any one solve this problem?

My header is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>


#define QUEUE_SIZE 300
#define MAX_CONN 10
#define TYPE_ROUTE 1
#define TYPE_TERMINAL 2
#define CONN_INIT false
#define CONN_ESTB true
#define CSPORT 39246



struct localInfo{
    char router_ID[16];

    int helloTime;
    int protocol_Version;
    int update_Interval;
    int area_ID;
    int neighborNum;
};
//shared information struct
```

and My main function is:

```
#include "BasicHeader.h"


int shared_hello, shared_lsa, shared_ping, shared_data, shared_localInfo;//using shared memory
pid_t childpid;//using for child process

int main(){
    printf("Starting router ... ");
    sleep(1);

    key_t keyForLocalInfo = ftok(".", 1);


    shared_localInfo = shmget ( keyForLocalInfo , sizeof(struct localInfo) , IPC_CREAT) ;
    if (shared_localInfo == -1) {perror("error creating");exit(1);}
    printf("shared_localInfo: %d\n", shared_localInfo);
    //creating the queue for shared_localInfo


    system("ipcs -m");
    //show the shm status
    //creating the sharing memory finished

    struct localInfo *routerInfo = (struct localInfo*) shmat (shared_localInfo, (void *)0, 0);
    if (routerInfo == NULL) {
        perror("shmat");exit(1);
    }

    routerInfo->area_ID = 0;
    routerInfo->helloTime = 45;
    routerInfo->neighborNum = 0;
    routerInfo->protocol_Version = 1;
    routerInfo->update_Interval = 180;
    shmdt(routerInfo);

    int err = 0;
    if  ((err = shmctl(shared_localInfo, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1))
        perror("shmctl shared_localInfo");


}
```

Comment: `shmat` must be returning NULL. Add a check for `routerInfo == NULL` and when that happens, output the value of `errno` to help debug the problem.

Comment: No, I use if else to check the pointer routerInfo, it is not NULL.

Comment: You sure it isn't your child that is blowing up?

Comment: I delete that part, the problem still exists. I use Mac terminal to run the program, is that the problem?

Comment: I think it is your permissions.  Try something like `shmget(keyForLocalInfo , sizeof(struct localInfo) , IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);` and make sure you delete any existing shm segment before hand.

Comment: How can I mark it as solved...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the permissions on `semget` to allow access e.g.

```
shmget(keyForLocalInfo, sizeof(struct localInfo), 
       IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);
```

Note that `shmat` returns a ptr set to -1, not NULL, and thus the error check was not catching the error.  The code should have been

```
struct localInfo *routerInfo = (struct localInfo*) shmat (shared_localInfo, (void *)0, 0);
if (routerInfo == (void *) -1)
{
    perror("shmat");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't match up with the claim that the segfault is happening well before the `fork()` call. The child never tries to read or write to the segment. The `shmctl` call in the child should, at worst, return `EINVAL` - not crash.

Comment: @Andrew Medico, "claim" is the appropriate word.  The code doesn't compile, neither you nor I know *what* the child does, OP has ruled out that he is getting errors attaching in the parent, the `shmctl` is in the parent (unless the child's `execl` fails), and what I outlined *will* happen some percentage of the time.

Comment: Although I delete the fork process, the problem still exists. I use Mac terminal to run these thing,using like "cc -o main main.c". Would it be the problem?

Comment: Ok, so then it is 100% before the fork.  Neither running in a terminal nor your compile command should have anything to do with it.  I'll delete this answer and perhaps you can post the code that is not working exactly as you have it?